# Failed to delete tag from remote GitHub repository in IntelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea, tags, git-remote

I'm trying to use IntelliJ to delete some tags from Git remote.

However, this always fails and I cannot get rid of them

These are the logs

```
08:39:08.636: [my-project] git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false fetch origin --recurse-submodules=no --progress --prune
From https://github.com/my-organization/my-project
 * [new tag]         my-tag--0.1.4 -> my-tag--0.1.4
08:40:54.900: [my-project] git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false tag -d my-tag--0.1.1
08:41:00.047: [my-project] git -c credential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false push --progress --porcelain origin :refs/tags/my-tag--0.1.1 --force-with-lease=refs/tags/my-tag--0.1.1:e7bd8bbdf2eee670782e0e0bb19fe3df6793dec9
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/my-organization/my-project.git'
To https://github.com/my-organization/my-project.git
!   (delete):refs/tags/my-tag--0.1.1    [rejected] (stale info)
Done
```

It seems, the tag that is rejected is not the tag I'm trying to delete (0.1.4 vs 0.1.1).

Is anyone else facing this problem and how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

Try force-pushing the tag from the Command line using plain `git push --force`. IntelliJ uses `--force-with-lease`, which appears to prevent force-pushing tags.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I see a "stale info", I start with a `git fetch`, in order to update any remote tracking data stored in the local repository.
In your case: `git fetch --prune` to clean up local references which are no longer in the remote repository.
But a fetch from IntelliJ IDEA seems to [always use `--prune` anyway](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360008179240--Git-Is-VCS-Git-Fetch-always-done-with-pruning-?page=1#community_comment_360001614060).

The remote tag might have been moved or deleted since you last fetched.

Then you can try a push for deleting your tag.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I did an update multiple times, and also force pushed after I deleted tags locally under the assumption that those deletes are automatically pushed with it. As far as I know, update does a fetch for all branches. Those locally deleted tags always reappear after the update, so I believe they must be available on remote

Comment: @MarianKlühspies OK and if you do a fetch explicitly, and then your push --delete, would that work?

Comment: I did that and it has no effect sadly